Как создать пользовательский слой и использовать его данные на своем сайте с картой?
Хочу создать свой слой карты в конструкторе. Взять произвольные области (их будет много), города и задать им краткое описание. И вот этот слой с данными хочу использовать (хотя бы просто показывать) на своем сайте с картой. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать?

На карту Яндекс можно добавить свои полигоны.
Примеры на JS API 2.1 и на JS API 3.0:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_spatial
https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/examples/cases/create-polygon
А можно создать полностью свой кастомный слой:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_map
https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/examples/cases/custom-map
Есть и вариант попроще — Конструктор карт.
